# Why does this Instagram oEmbed html not fit in Swift WKWebView?

Tags: html, swift, instagram, wkwebview, oembed

I am having trouble getting the entire Instagram embed html to render inside this WKWebView.
The following url is being use to query the api:

```
/instagram_oembed?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/B4x4RtagRoH/?igshid=rmiahm71silp&maxwidth=658
```

The maxWidth is described here in the Instagram docs: [Instagram oEmbed Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/instagram-oembed)

> Note: The frame of the WKWebView I am using has a width of 394 (translated to pixels would be 1182; which is why I'm using the APIs max possible width value of 658).
> Also, The WKWebView is added to a container UIView and constrained to its edges.

The call returns a json object with an html key that consists of the post. It starts with a `<blockquote>` and it wouldn't render properly so I wrapped it in a `<HTML>` and `<HEAD>` tag like so:

```
func embed(html: String, baseURL: URL? = nil) {
    let htmlStart = "<HTML><HEAD><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=658, shrink-to-fit=yes\"></HEAD><BODY>"
    let htmlEnd = "</BODY></HTML>"
    let htmlString = "\(htmlStart)\(html)\(htmlEnd)"

    let script = """
                            var script = document.createElement('script');
                            script.src = 'https://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js';
                            document.head.appendChild(script);
                         """
            
    let userScript = WKUserScript(source: script, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
            
    configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)
            
    debugPrint("htmlString: \(htmlString)")
    loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: baseURL)
    
}
```

This is how it is currently rendering:

[image]

Why is the content of the html not resizing the height correctly?

What can I do to try to fit the entire html in the WKWebView?